# When is the ring of functions of a quotient variety a smooth algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, invariant-theory

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Let $k[V]$ be the ring of functions on V. Since $V$ is a smooth (non-singular) variety, we know that $\mathbb C[V]$ is a smooth $k$-algebra.

Assume that $G$ is a finite subgroup of $GL(V)$. In general, the quotient variety $V/G$ is not smooth. However, what can we say about the ring of functions $k[V]^G$ of $V/G$? Is it smooth or non-smooth?
If it is non-smooth under what conditions it is smooth? Thank you.

Comment: What's your definition of a smooth algebra? The first definition that comes to mind is that a ring of functions ought to be smooth iff the associated variety is, but since you're asking this question that's clearly not your definition.

Comment: I use the definition from Loday's book "Cyclic Homology". Let $k$ be a field. A commutative and unital $k$-algebra $A$ is smooth over $k$ if it is flat over $k$ and if for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$, the kernel $J$ of the localized map $\mu_{\mathfrak{m}}:(A\otimes_kA)_{\mu^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})}\to A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is generated by a regular sequence in $(A\otimes_kA)_{\mu^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})}$.

Comment: If you have the book at your disposal, the definition is on page 102.

Comment: As per the result Loday states immediately following the definition (proposition 3.4.2), Loday's definition of smooth is equivalent to the standard definition of smoothness in the presence of a noetherian assumption. So $k[V]^G$ is smooth iff $V/G$ is smooth.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of smooth you state in the comments can be phrased geometrically as saying the diagonal $\Delta : X \hookrightarrow X \times_k X$ is a regular embedding. Note the flatness is automatic since $k$ is a field. Using the fact that $\Delta^*(I/I^2) \cong \Omega_{X/k}$ where $I$ is the ideal of $\Delta(X)$ and some standard results on formal smoothness, its not hard to see that this definition is equivalent to saying that $X/k$ is formally smooth.

If $X$ is a variety (or more generally for any morphism of finite presentation) formal smoothness is the same as smoothness so the question is really to characterize when is $V/G = \mathrm{Spec} k[V]^G$ smooth when $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and $G$ a finite group acting linearly. This is answered by the following well known theorem. First we need some background.

**Definition:** Let $G \subset GL(V)$. An non-identity element $g \in G$ is called a pseudoreflection if it fixes a codimension $1$ subspace of $V$.

**Theorem:** (Chevalley-Shephard-Todd) With $G$ and $V$ as above, the following are equivalent:

1. $G$ is generated by pseudoreflections.
2. $V/G$ is smooth.
3. $k[V]^G$ is isomorphic to a polynomial algebra.
4. $k[V]$ is flat as a $k[V]^G$ algebra.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer.